# explain why a class can only extend one parent class in Java?

Tags: java, extend

Why can it only extend one parent class? Why not more? I have looked online but I can't get a straight answer

Comment: Because the only straight answer can come from Java themselves ...

Comment: Because java doesn't support multiple inheritence. what you can do is implement interfaces

Answer (score 0):

Because Java **DOES NOT** support [Multiple Inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance).